# Node JS, make HTTPS request synchronously from two links

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, rest

I want to make a HTTPS request to an external link through Node JS. On my first call, I need to fetch user id by looping through several users. On my second call, I need to input that user id in the URL link and fetch user properties. Keep repeating this process till I go through all users. The end goal is to store data of every user in a JSON format. There is no front-end involved. Any direction/advice is much appreciated.

I can't share the actual link due to api keys. But here is the hypothetical scenario. I only show 2 users here. I have about 10,000 users in my actual data set.

**Link 1**
https://www.google.com/all_users

**JSON Output**

```
{
            "name": "joe",
            "uri": "/id/UserObject/User/1234-1234",
},
{
            "name": "matt",
            "uri": "/id/UserObject/User/5678-5678",
}
```

**Link 2**
https://www.google.com//id/UserObject/User/1234-1234

**JSON Output**

```
{
            "name": "joe",
            "uri": "/id/UserObject/User/1234-1234",
            "Property Values": {
              "height": "2",
              "location": "canada"
             },
            "Other Values": {
              "work": "google",
              "occupation": "developer"
             }
}
```

**Nested JSON**

```
{
    "PropertySetClassChildrenResponse": {
        "PropertySetClassChildren": {
            "PropertySetInstances": {
                "totalCount": "1",
                "Elements": [
                    {
                        "name": "SystemObject",
                        "uri": "/type/PropertySetClasses/SystemObject"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use "q" (basically based on promise) or async.waterfall() for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers above helped me go further with my solution and get the desired outcome. However, I spent a lot of time trying to understand node, promises in node, making an API call, etc. Hopefully, this will help to a beginner level node developer.

**NODE** 
Node.js® is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient. Node.js' package ecosystem, npm, is the largest ecosystem of open source libraries in the world.

If you are a JavaScript developer, you would prefer to use Node as you wouldn't have to spend time learning a new language like Java or Python.

**GOAL**
Make a HTTPS call to an external link to fetch all server URIs. Pass in the URI as a param to create a second link to fetch all server properties. Loop through to all server uris and properties. Refer the original post on the top for the data structure. The external link also required basic auth and headers.

**CODE**
Install NPM modules request (https call), bluebird (promises) and lodash(utility) and express(node framework).

/

```
********************** MODULES/DEPENDENCIES **********************/
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var _ = require("lodash");

/********************** INITIATE APP **********************/
var app = express();

console.log("Starting node server...");

/**
 * Your HTTPS GET Request Function
 * @param url - The url to GET
 * @return Promise - Promise containing the JSON response. 
 */
function get(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        // var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString("base64");

        var options = {
            url: url,
            headers: {
                // 'Authorization': auth,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        console.log("Calling GET: ", url);

        if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
            console.log("Rejecting node tls");
            process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
        }

        request(options, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                // console.log("THIS IS BODY: ", body);
                resolve(body);
            }
        });
    });
}

/********************** GET DATA FUNCTION **********************/
function getServerData() {
    /********************** URI VARIABLES **********************/
    var username = 'username',
        password = 'password',
        role = 'Read-Only',
        url_host = 'https://link.com:10843';

    /********************** URL 1 **********************/
    var url1 = url_host + '/type/PropertySetClasses/SystemObject/Server/?maxResults=1000&username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&role=' + role;

    console.log("Getting server data...", url1);

    /********************** GET REQUEST 1 **********************/
    return get(url1)
    .then(function(res) {

        console.log("Got response!");

        res = JSON.parse(res);
        res = res.PropertySetClassChildrenResponse.PropertySetClassChildren.PropertySetInstances.Elements;

        // console.log("THIS IS RES: ", res);

        /********************** FETCH URI FROM RES NESTED OBJECT **********************/
        var server_ids = _.map(res, function(server) {
            return server.uri;
        });

        console.log("Calling server urls", server_ids);

        // Loop through the object to get what you need:
        // Set a counter though so we know once we are done.

        return Promise.map(server_ids, function (id) {
            var url2 = url_host + id + '?username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&role=' + role;

            console.log("Calling URL", url2);

            return get(url2)
            .then(function(res2) {
                res2 = JSON.parse(res2);
                var elements = res2.PropertySetInstanceResponse.PropertySetInstance.PropertyValues.Elements;

                console.log("Got second response", res2, elements);
                return elements;
            });
        })
        .then(function (allUrls) {
            console.log("Got all URLS", allUrls);
            return allUrls;
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    });

};

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("Server listening and booted on: " + 8080);

    app.get("/serverInfo", function (req, res) {
        console.log("Calling server info");

        return getServerData()
        .then(function(userData) {
            var userData = JSON.stringify(userData, null, "\t");
            console.log("This is USERDATA Data: ", userData);

            res.send(userData);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);

            res.send({
                __error: err,
                message: err.message
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but this should point you in the right direction. It uses Promises and assumes that run in an ES6 environment:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

fetchAllUsers()
.then(extractUserUris)
.then(extractUserIds)
.then(buildUserDetailRequests)
.then(Promise.all) // run all the user detail requests in parallel
.then(allUserData => {
  // allUserData is an array of all users' data
});

function fetchAllUsers() {
  return rp('https://api.whatever.com/all_users');
}

function extractUserUris(users) {
  return users.map(user => user.uri);
}

function extractUserIds(userUris) {
  return userUris.map(userUri => userUri.split('/').pop());
}

function buildUserDetailRequests(userIds) {
  return userIds.map(userId => rp("https://api.whatever.com/user/" + userId));
}
```

Comment: @Ace- can you please help me resolve an error? I get an error- Unhandled rejection Request Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: @MihirPatel it means you have a wrong URL somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the [request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to make your HTTP requests easier.

```
> npm install request
```

Then you would obtain a list of all users with something like this:

```js
var request = require('request');

request.get({url: "https://example.org/all_users"}, handleUsersResponse);
```

You'd handle the request response like this:

```
function(err, response, body) {
   if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
       // parse json (assuming array of users)
       var users = JSON.parse(body);

       // iterate through each user and obtain user info
       for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
           var userUri = users[i].uri;
           obtainUserInfo(userUri)
       }
   }
}
```

`obtainUserInfo` function would be similar to the above code.

**One important thing to keep in mind** is that since the HTTP requests are being made asynchronously, when you make the requests in a loop, the next iteration of the loop does not wait until the work is finished before moving to the next iteration and starting the next request.  So in effect, your loop would start *all* the HTTP requests nearly in parallel.  This can easily overwhelm both your client and the server.  One way to get around this is to use a worker queue to enqueue the work and ensure that only a maximum number of HTTP requests are being executed at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do synchronous calls, it defeats the purpose of using Node. So by the Node powers invested in me by the State of Texas I hereby cast that synchronous way I thinking out of you!

Just kidding :), but let's do this the Node way. 
Install these two libraries:
`sudo npm install Promise` 
`sudo npm install request`

And set your code to look like:

```js
var Promise = require('promise');
var request = require('request');
//Get your user data, and print the data in JSON:
getUserData()
  .then(function(userData) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ' +err);
  });

/**
 * Prepares an Object containing data for all users.
 * @return Promise - Contains object with all user data.
 */
function getUserData() {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    // Make the first request to get the user IDs:
    var url1 = 'https://www.google.com/all_users';
    get(url1)
      .then(function(res) {
        res = JSON.parse(res);
        // Loop through the object to get what you need:
        // Set a counter though so we know once we are done.
        var counter = 0; 
        for (x=0; x<res.users.length; x++) {
          var url2 = 'https://www.google.com//id/UserObject/User/';
          url2 = url2 + res.users.id; //Wherever the individual ID is stored.
          var returnDataArr = [];
          get(url2)
            .then(function(res2) {
              // Get what you need from the response from the 2nd URL.
              returnDataArr.push(res2);
              counter++;
              if (counter === res.users.length) {
                fulfill({data: returnDataArr}); //Return/Fulfill an object containing an array of the user data.
              }
            }).catch(function(err) {
              // Catch any errors from the 2nd HTTPS request:
              reject('Error: ' +err);
            });
        }).catch(function(err) {
          // Catch any errors from the 1st HTTPS request:
          reject('Error: ' +err);
  });
}

/**
 * Your HTTPS GET Request Function
 * @param url - The url to GET
 * @return Promise - Promise containing the JSON response. 
 */
 function get(url) {
   return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
     var options = {
       url: url,
       headers: {
       'Header Name': 'Header Value',
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     };
     request(options, function(err, res, body) {
       if (err) {
         reject(err);
       } else {
         fulfill(body);
       }
     });
   });
 }
```

So what this Promise does, is that it ***returns*** the value once we actually have it. In the code above, we are first getting that list of users, and then as we parse through it, we are making a new asynchronous HTTP request to get the additional data on it. Once we get the user data, we push it to an array. 
Finally, once our counter hits its endpoint, we know that we have gotten all the user data, and so we call `fulfill` which essentially means `return`, and it returns an object containing an array of the user data.

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Hello, from the Windy city. I am trying out your solution. Quick question- how and where do I pass the header for the get request?

Comment: Good question, and I thought that you may have wanted to know. I have updated the function appropriately to show support for headers.

Comment: I am required username and password on the url. I thought it was due to double quotes. Switched it to single quotes but still get the same error.

Comment: Lookup the options for the request library. You probably have to add the auth as a header, maybe you have to base64 encode the username/password?. The header should look like: `'Authorization': 'Basic 'username:password'`